# Scala convert string to list with criteria

Tags: scala

String like this `"(school A and school B) or (school C or school D)"`.
so string will be as following:

```
val queryString = "(school A and school B) or (school C or school D)"
```

expected output

```
val firstList = List ( "school A", "school B", "and" )
val secondList = List ( "school C", "school D" , "or")
val operatorList = List("or")
```

and `queryString` should be `and` criteria also like this :

```
val queryString = "(school A and school B) and (school C or school D)"
```

expected output

```
val firstList = List ( "school A", "school B", "and" )
val secondList = List ( "school C", "school D" , "or")
val operatorList = List("and")
```

also some time `queryString` should be only one criteria like this :

```
val queryString = "(school A and school B)"
```

expected output

```
val firstList = List ( "school A", "school B", "and" )
val secondList = empty list
val operatorList = empty list
```

`firstList` contains string first open and close brackets data `(school A and school B)` this will be in `firstList` as `List ( "school A", "school B", "and" )` same for `secondList`.

I do with last string as follow :

`val queryString = "(school A and school B)"`

This replace by `( and ) to ""` and split by `and`

```
queryString.replaceAll("\\(|\\)","").split("and")
```

this return `Array("school A ", " school B")` but in above code I manually split by `and` this work on  `(school A and school B)` only this string if string was to large then this logic was failed .

Comment: What did you do already?

Comment: @Odomontois I added code which I was tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advice to use parser combinator for this task.
Definetly it'll take some time for you to figure out how it works.
But here is basic implementation that works for half of your samples.

You can improve it to work properly for all scenarios.

```
class SParser extends RegexParsers {

  def word = "\\w+".r
  def or = "or"

  def oper = "and" | "or"
  def oneQ = "(" ~ word ~ oper  ~ word ~ ")" ^^ {
    case _ ~ s1 ~ op ~ s2 ~ _ => List(s1, s2, op)
  }

  def q1 = oneQ ~ oper ~ oneQ ^^ {
    case s1 ~ op ~ s2  =>
      println("firstList : " + s1)
      println("secondList: " + s2)
      println("operatorList: " + op)
      (s1, s2, op)
  }

  def parse(s: String) = {
    println(s"Start parse: $s")
    val res = parseAll(q1, s)
    println(res)
    res
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
  val s = new SParser()
  s.parse("(SchoolA and SchoolB) or (SchoolC and SchoolD)")
  s.parse("(SchoolA and SchoolB) and (SchoolC and SchoolD)")
  // s.parse("(SchoolA and SchoolB)") // will not work for it. need implement...
```

Output:

```
Start parse: (SchoolA and SchoolB) or (SchoolC and SchoolD)
firstList : List(SchoolA, SchoolB, and)
secondList: List(SchoolC, SchoolD, and)
operatorList: or

Start parse: (SchoolA and SchoolB) and (SchoolC and SchoolD)
firstList : List(SchoolA, SchoolB, and)
secondList: List(SchoolC, SchoolD, and)
operatorList: and
```

**UPDATE**

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
class SParser extends RegexParsers {

  def space = "\\s".r
  def schholName = "\\w+\\s\\w".r // regex for <school X>

  def and = "and"
  def or = "or"
  def eof = "$".r

  def oneQ(oper: String) = "(" ~ repsep(schholName, oper) ~ ")" ^^ {
    case _ ~ s1 ~ _ => s1 ++ (1 until s1.size).map( _ => oper) // add operators at the end
  }

  def allOneQ = oneQ(and) | oneQ(or)

  def q1(oper: String) = repsep(allOneQ, oper) ^^ {
    case s1  =>
      val res = s1 ++ (1 until s1.size).map(_ => oper)
      println("Lists : " + res)
      res
  }

  def fullQ = q1(and) ~ eof | q1(or) ~ eof


  def parse(s: String) = {
    println(s"Start parse: $s")
    val res = parseAll(fullQ, s)
    println(res)
    res
  }

}
```

Usage

```
val s = new SParser()
s.parse("(school A or school B)")
s.parse("(school A and school B and school E)")
s.parse("(school A or school B or school E) or (school C and school D)")
```

Result

```
Start parse: (school A or school B)
Lists : List(List(school A, school B, or))
Start parse: (school A and school B and school E)
Lists : List(List(school A, school B, school E, and, and))
Start parse: (school A or school B or school E) or (school C and school D)
Lists : List(List(school A, school B, school E, or, or))
Lists : List(List(school A, school B, school E, or, or), List(school C, school D, and), or)
```

Comment: `import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers`

Comment: Added some `if else` in `parse` method to check string contains `( or )` and added another `method` for parsing string which not contains `( and ) `. This work fine, Thanks for your help. I will work more on scala parser :)

Comment: here one problem if my string contains more than two words like this `(school A and school B or schoolC)` then how should this `def oneQ = "(" ~ word ~ oper  ~ word ~ ")" ^^ {` create dynamically, because every time I count the word and then create different functions for that. Is any other way to create this dynamically?

Comment: what result expected to be ?

Comment: @Mr.V. if I passed this string `((school A and school B) or schoolC)` then out put should be `List(List(SchoolA, SchoolB, and),schoolC,or)` or If I passed this simple string `(school A or school B or schoolC or schoolD)` then out put will be `List(schoolA,schoolB,schoolC,schoolD,or,or)` like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to impove Mr. V. answer with [parboiled2](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2)

### Structure

While it's beyond the question bounds, let me introduce some appropriate structure for checking complex conditions

```
trait Query {
  def check(valid: String => Boolean): Boolean
}

case class School(name: String) extends Query {
  def check(valid: (String) => Boolean) = valid(name)
}

case class And(queries: Seq[Query]) extends Query {
  def check(valid: (String) => Boolean) = queries.forall(_.check(valid))
}

case class Or(queries: Seq[Query]) extends Query {
  def check(valid: (String) => Boolean) = queries.exists(_.check(valid))
}

case object False extends Query {
  def check(valid: (String) => Boolean) = false
}

case object True extends Query {
  def check(valid: (String) => Boolean) = true
}
```

Here `School(A)` will be parse equivalent of `school A`
`And`, `Or` are combiners for `and`\ `or` conditions.
`True` and `False` are utilitary constant conditions.

Each `Query` can run some queries, with predefined results for leaf `School`s

### Parser

Lets create parser fur such structure via [parboiled2](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2) which is way faster than standard scala parser combinators, suggested by Mr. V.

```
object Query {
  class QueryParser(val input: ParserInput) extends Parser {
    def element: Rule1[Query] = rule {school | group}
    def group: Rule1[Or] = rule {"(" ~ WS ~ disjunction ~ WS ~ ")"}
    def conjunction: Rule1[And] = rule {element.+(and) ~> And.apply _}
    def disjunction: Rule1[Or] = rule {conjunction.+(or) ~> Or.apply _}

    def school = rule {"school " ~ WS ~ capture(schoolName) ~> School.apply _}
    def schoolName = rule {oneOrMore(CharPredicate.Alpha)}
    def or = rule {WS ~ "or" ~ WS}
    def and = rule {WS ~ "and" ~ WS}
    def WS = rule {zeroOrMore(anyOf(" \n\r\t\f"))}
  }

  def parse(str: String) = new QueryParser(str).disjunction.run().toOption
}
```

### Using

Now you can try to parse and run come queries

```
val query = Query.parse("school A and ( school D or school B)").getOrElse(False)

query.check(Set("A", "D"))  // true
query.check(Set("A", "E"))  // false
```